# How to fix compiler error "unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateRenerer referenced in function _SDL_main"

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a window with a red background, however `SDL_CreateRenderer()` is causing problems.

My code:

```
#include <SDL.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 500
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 500

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* render;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 1)
        return -1;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Up Left", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, NULL);
    render = SDL_CreateRenerer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(render);

    SDL_RenderPresent(render);

    SDL_Delay(5000);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the compiler error:

```
unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateRenerer referenced in function _SDL_main
```

I have included the SDL2 folder in my VS folder.

Under properties I've done:

```
VC++ Dictionaries > Include Directories

VC++ Dictionaries > Library Directories
Linker > Input > SDL2.lib
Linker > Input > SDL2main.lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left the letter 'd' out of Renderer.